# Sound Forge Pro: how to save a volume envelope?

Tags: sound, editing, automation

I spend an hour creating an envelope volume for an audio file in Sound Forge and I need to apply the same envelope to another file. How to save this envelope and how to then apply it to a different file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The envelope is tied to the file itself so it cannot be saved separately. You might be able to open the other file in a separate window and copy the envelope over to that window.